# Fill combobox with only 1 kind of data

Tags: c#, ms-access

Assuming that i have the database items:

Hello
Hello
Hello

I just want to display only one "Hello"

Here is my code....

```
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select *from login", con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            combo1.Items.Add(dr["dtlogin"].ToString());

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = dr["dtlogin"].ToString(); 

if (!combo1.Items.Contains(value))
{
    combo1.Items.Add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.idbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get first column of the first row. Other rows are ignored.

I assume they are string, you can do;

```
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select dtlogin from login", con);)
{
   string s = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   combo1.Items.Add(s);
}
```

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbCommand` and `con`.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the item before adding using [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb352880%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
     if(!combo1.Items.Contains(dr["dtlogin"].ToString()))
     {
            combo1.Items.Add(dr["dtlogin"].ToString());
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you r  looking for distinct value's to be bind to ur combobox then use this.

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select distinct * from login", con);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        combo1.Items.Add(dr["dtlogin"].ToString());

    }
```